# Technical clothing brands for extra long arms?

Tags: clothing, ice-climbing

I'm a +5 in the ape index, (6'2" tall, with almost a 6'7" wingspan) Buying nice fitting jackets has never been a luxury I could enjoy. My solution for a while was to buy jackets made for ice climbing, because they are designed to have your arms extended over your head, which made a perfect fit for me for normal use. My problem now is that I'm getting into ice climbing, and my sleeves just aren't long enough when I'm hanging from my tools. I fit most Medium Tall stuff pretty well, the problem is that not many brands make their nice technical gear in a Medium Tall, just the general, more affordable stuff, and they usually end up being a bit long in the body.

What brands of technical wear are out there that have ***extra long*** sleeves?

Comment: Cycling fleeces and jackets usually have longer sleeves.

Answer (score 5):

The UK company [Rab](https://rab.equipment/) have a reputation for selling jackets and tops with longish sleeves. I'm 6'3" (I don't know about 'wingspan') and find quite a lot of their jackets/tops have sleeves more than long enough for me, perhaps a bit too long in some cases!

Also, here is a link to Rab's sizing guide, which also gives sleeve lengths: [sizing guide](https://support-uk.rab.equipment/hc/en-us/articles/115004258069--Sizing-Guide-Men)

Comment: They do look longer in the pictures, but not much longer than typical technical climbing jackets. Imagine each of your arms was about 2" longer, do you think your sleeves would stay at your wrists while you were hanging by your arms? I've never heard of Rab before, thanks for the link.

Comment: Difficult to say without trying something on, but try googling "rab long arms" and see what I mean.

Comment: Apparently 'rab' is also slang for 'Arabian', and 'long arms' can equate to 'automatic rifles'. A google image search for 'rab long arms' returns almost as many pictures of terrorist arsenals as it does a clothing brand...

Comment: Hmm, I don't get that. It must be Google using country of origin to base the search on. I just measured my arm spread at 78" (6'6") fingertip to fingertip and my Rab stuff is plenty long enough.

Comment: No? Maybe it's just [google.ca](https://www.google.ca/search?q=rab+long+arms&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=zgz&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=fflb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=HBtmVKrZIajGiAL81IGYDw&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1680&bih=939). My wing span is not even an inch longer than yours, so that is very encouraging! What size is your Rab jacket?

Comment: XL - they fit me very well (I have > 1).

Comment: I have same experience with Rab, but I'm in S size.

Comment: In many Cyrillic languages 'rab' transcripts to 'slave'. That's making things extremely confusing!

Comment: Rab the company, was started by famous Scottish climber Rab Carrington. I have edited my reply above to include Rab's sizing guide which might help as they also give sleeve lengths "from centre back neck to cuff".

Comment: I have a Rab softshell, and yes it has loooong sleeves, good for reaching. I'm a medium and 5'9" and the sleeves could definitely be shorter. They make excellent gear by the way.

Comment: I find most things too short in the sleeves (even most bike jerseys), but my Rab jacket normally  comes halfway down my hands.  I did choose the size for going over lots of layers, and usually wear less. BTW Google obviously knows I like looking at outdoor gear rather than guns and I have no search issues

Answer (score 2):

[Jöttnar](https://www.jottnar.com/) is maybe an option? They have extra long arms.